# How to avoid null values when using Outlay::all()

Tags: laravel

Hello i have this line of code:

```
return response()->json([OutlayResource::collection(Outlay::all())], 200);
```

And the code of `resource` is:

```
 return [
            'value_with_currencies' => unserialize($this->value_with_currencies),
            'status' => $this->status,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
```

Now the values come correct but for some values `status` is null and i want to make a verification that avoids showing values with `status` null. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did this and worked:

```
return response()->json([OutlayResource::collection(Outlay::whereNotNull("status")->get())], 200);
```